# Fazer border-bottom ficar na mesma largura do texto

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código

```
footer ul li h3 {
font: 700 15px/40px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4da494;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #4da494;
margin: 25px 0;
width: 50%;
cursor: default;}
```

Coloquei o **width: 50%** apenas para ter a borda ficar fixa, e poder visualizar. Mas, eu gostaria que a largura do "border-bottom" fosse equivalente à palavra que está dentro de **H3**. No caso que ela acompanhasse a largura da palavra *Institucional*.

```
<h3>Institucional</h3>
```

Comment: Por favor, elabore um [mcve] e verifique a possibilidade de utilizar um elemento `span` para definir a borda.

Comment: Funcionou com **span**

Comment: @FelipeStoker se não quiser adicionar elementos a mais, pode adicionar a seguinte propriedade na sua regra de CSS: `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Eu sei :D Mas mesmo assim melhore a pergunta para deixar mais claro o que precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta aplicar a borda a um elemento `span` dentro do elemento `h3`. Veja um exemplo:

```css
h3 {
  background: #FFFFE0;
}

h3 > span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>Stack Overflow em Português</span></h3>
```

> **Nota:** o fundo amarelado no exemplo acima serve apenas para indicar as dimensões do elemento `h3`.

O elemento `span`, por padrão, possui `display: inline` e se adapta ao tamanho do seu conteúdo, por isso a borda é aplicada exatamente do tamanho do texto.

Como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219367/fazer-border-bottom-ficar-na-mesma-largura-do-texto?noredirect=1#comment450175_219367), também seroa possível utilizar `display: inline-block` para o próprio elemento `h3`, mas isso traz algumas preocupações em questão do layout em torno deste elemento, pois se houverem elementos `inline`, estes serão movidos para o lado do `h3`.

Answer (score 0):

A tag `h3` possui o tamanho de `1.3em`, logo você pode utilizar esta medida para configurar o `border-bottom`:

```
border-bottom: 1.17em solid blue;
```

A maioria dos browser renderizara as fontes nos seguintes tamanhos:

```
h1 é 2 em
h2 é 1.5 em
h3 é 1.17 em
h4 é 1.33 em
h5 é .83 em
h6 é .67 em
```

Informação tirada do [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)